# Including more fields in (mysql) database table results in lower (database) server load?

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a web system which on one hand must store values in a mysql database each day and on the other hand (e.g., a private member page) must retrieve dayvalues between a (random) startdate and enddate.

I think an important design goal is to minimise the server load when retrieving the values, e.g., the frequency of accessing the (database) server, and based on this design goal my plan is allocating a field for every day value, where one record contains 31 dayvalues per month. In this way accessing the data of say, the last year only requires retrieving 12 records (as opposed to retrieving 365 records each with a single day value).

Is my logic correct, or does it not matter with respect to server load which of the two database table options (records with 31 day fields vs records with a single dayfield per record) on choose? Or do miss a better third option?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this is an unnecessary optimization that *may* be justified in huge environments with billions of queries, but most likely not in your case.

Having columns bound to day values or month names is a bad idea. Build a sound database architecture using [normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) instead, and worry about performance later.

Comment: thnx for your comment and tip. Why do you think having columns bound to day values is a bad idea? Another question: at roughly what amount of queries per year you think scalability will become important? I dont think my system will have billions of queries, but I thought it was good to even prepare an initial version to be scalable. In my case, that may be a few tens of millions in 3-5 years time.

Comment: @user having a column structure like that is bad design. The standard way of doing this is having a master table